# Mutable methods with lifetimes and later references

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

Consider the following code:

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    borrowed: &'a u8,
    owned_one: Vec<u8>,
    owned_two: Vec<u8>,
    output: usize
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn do_stuff(&mut self) {
        self.output = self.owned_one.len();
        let zipped = self.owned_one.iter().zip(self.owned_two.iter());
        Self::subroutine(&zipped);
    }
    
    fn subroutine<Arg: Iterator<Item=(&'a u8, &'a u8)>>(_zipped: &Arg) {}
}

fn main() {
    let num = 0u8;
    let mut foo = Foo {
        borrowed: &num,
        owned_one: vec![0],
        owned_two: vec![1],
        output: 0
    };
    foo.do_stuff();
    let _out = &foo.output;
}
```

([playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=1bf45b1f9d605ead32fd3278019c809c))

It doesn't compile, producing the following error:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/lib.rs:12:9
   |
8  | impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
9  |     fn do_stuff(&mut self) {
   |                 - let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
...
12 |         Self::subroutine(&zipped);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ argument requires that `'1` must outlive `'a`
```

I don't *fully* understand the complaint - surely `self` would always have the lifetime assigned to the class we're `impl`ementing? - but I can understand that both arguments to `zip()` need to last the same time. So I change `do_stuff` to take `&'a mut self`.

```rust
struct Foo<'a> {
    borrowed: &'a u8,
    owned_one: Vec<u8>,
    owned_two: Vec<u8>,
    output: usize
}

impl<'a> Foo<'a> {
    fn do_stuff(&'a mut self) {
        self.output = self.owned_one.len();
        let zipped = self.owned_one.iter().zip(self.owned_two.iter());
        Self::subroutine(&zipped);
    }
    
    fn subroutine<Arg: Iterator<Item=(&'a u8, &'a u8)>>(_zipped: &Arg) {}
}

fn main() {
    let num = 0u8;
    let mut foo = Foo {
        borrowed: &num,
        owned_one: vec![0],
        owned_two: vec![1],
        output: 0
    };
    foo.do_stuff();
    let _out = &foo.output;
}
```

However, now compilation fails with:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `foo.output` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/lib.rs:27:16
   |
26 |     foo.do_stuff();
   |     -------------- mutable borrow occurs here
27 |     let _out = &foo.output;
   |                ^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                |
   |                immutable borrow occurs here
   |                mutable borrow later used here
```

Why has specifying a lifetime for `self` in the argument list for `do_stuff` meant that I suddenly can't take the immutable reference to `foo` later; and what can I do about it?

Comment: IIRC, you are borrowing a member of `self` which is also borrowing `self` since it owns those values.  I think there's a workaround with temporary scopes you can use to mutate, but it might make more sense to wrap `output` in a `RefCell` for interior mutability instead.

Comment: @MaximilianBurszley I probably could fix it by RefCell'ing `output`; but without the lifetime on the `&self` I wouldn't need to.

Comment: @Stargateur ok, it's likely to be a mistake. Is there something I can do that would mean I don't need it? Why _do_ I need it?

Comment: I believe they are arguing against side effects with their comment and OOP-oriented designs in Rust code, but they didn't expand on their thought when prompted.

Comment: @Stargateur - ah, you fixed it by giving the argument to `subroutine` a specific and different lifetime?

Comment: Thanks, that makes much more sense now that you explained what you were saying originally @Stargateur It's difficult to understand quippy "you're doing it wrong" comments without context to _why_ what they're doing is wrong.

Comment: @Stargateur if you can write up that fix as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

writing `fn do_stuff(&'a mut self)` in this context mean that the lifetime of this borrow of self, must life as long as what this self has borrow `borrowed`. That very often not what you want.

Your mistake is here `fn subroutine<Arg: Iterator<Item=(&'a u8, &'a u8)>>(_zipped: &Arg) {}`. Think of lexical meaning of your declaration. Your method return nothing but require a "parent" lifetime ? There is no reason to. The simple solution is simply to introduce a new lifetime for your Item. Like `fn subroutine<'i, Arg: Iterator<Item=(&'i u8, &'i u8)>>(_zipped: &Arg) {}`. Unless your function return something link to `'a`, no lifetime of parent should be here.

Also, it's better to accept `IntoIterator` it's more generic, and there is no reason to take it by reference and finally when you have such complex generic better use `where`, and really really if you want to be pedantic you need two lifetime:

```rust
fn subroutine<'i, 'j, Arg>(_zipped: Arg)
where
    Arg: IntoIterator<Item = (&'i u8, &'j u8)>,
{
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks for all the tips. Thinking about it, why does `subroutine` need explicit lifetimes at all?

Comment: @Chowlett cause you wanted reference to u8, a reference require a lifetime, sometime compiler require explicit lifetime. Just remove them https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e16e1ce798fca087ff2f7d8cced69d3f

Comment: In reality, one of the two things in the zip is not a primitive, so I do need a ref. Just - I realise the ref _has_ a lifetime, but it doesn't matter what it is, so why do I have to specify it?

Comment: @Chowlett because you must https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/error_codes/E0637.html